# How can I read a NSNumber from an array?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsnumber

I am trying to put a NSNumber to an array with this:

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
[[array objectAtIndex:0] setValue:n forKey:@"1"];
```

Then I have an action, which I want it to print the n.intValue from the array. I wrote it like this:

```
-(IBAction)action:(id)sender {
NSNumber *n = [[array objectAtIndex:0 ] valueForKey:@"1"];
NSLog(@"%d",n.intValue);
}
```

The problem is that it is printing 0 instead of 1.

How can I rewrite this to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do like this

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
 [array addObject:n];
  NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0 ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, the first line fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `setValue:n forKey:@"1"` on the first object of the array. This won't insert the `NSNumber` object into the array and I don't think whatever object is in that array will respond to that key. So, what you are logging is actually a nil `NSNumber` object's `intValue`. Which is why you are getting 0.

What you need to do is use an `NSMutableArray` and not `NSArray`. You can insert the `NSNumber` as

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
[mutableArray insertObject:n atIndex:0];
```

and read it

```
-(IBAction)action:(id)sender {
NSNumber *n = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%d",n.intValue);
}
```